# Angular 4: (click) function not binding inside of *ngIf

Tags: angular

I am having a very strange problem with Angular 4.

With this code:

**Component:**

```
export class ExampleComponent {

    ...

    public toggleDropdown() {
        this.showDropdown = !this.showDropdown;
    }

    public runClickEvent(e) {
        console.log('click event ran');
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<button class="btn btn-link btn-lg"
        (click)="toggleDropdown()"
        (blur)="toggleDropdown()"
        [ngClass]="{ 'open': showDropdown }">

    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
</button>

<div class="dropdown" [@ngBodySlider] *ngIf="showDropdown">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:" (click)="runClickEvent($event)">
                <div class="list-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-object-ungroup"></i>
                </div>

                <span>Run Event</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For some reason the `(click)` function inside the dropdown does not bind if the `<div.dropdown>` is hidden with the `*ngIf`, however, if I remove the `*ngIf`, the `(click)` function runs just fine.

I know this is possible because I am using the same idea in other parts of my code, so I am at a loss. I have no idea why this is not binding inside of the `*ngIf`.

Any ideas would be appreciated because this is driving me crazy :)

Comment: What do you mean *"the div is hidden with the ngIf"*? It's not *hidden*; if `showDropdown` isn't truth-y, that div *doesn't exist* in the resulting DOM. It's not clear to me precisely what is behaving unexpectedly.

Comment: The click event inside the dropdown is not firing when I use the *ngIf to show/hide it. I know it removes it from the DOM completely, but I said show/hide instead of add/remove. Sorry I should have made my wording more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just figured it out...

It was because of the (blur) event on the button. When I clicked the link in the dropdown, the blur executes before the (click) event, thus unbinding it before it executes.

By removing the (blur) event on the button, I was able to get the (click) event inside the dropdown to work correctly.